# The "Play" button isn't launching the game

Tags: technical-issues, back-to-the-future-the-game

I've bought the first episode of [Back To The Future](http://www.telltalegames.com/bttf) using a promotional code. Then I've downloaded `bttf_101_setup.exe` file and ran it. As expected, Windows 7 32-bit asked to run it as administrator, as the setup requires extra privileges. Then, it was installed successfully.

Then I try to launch the game from the desktop shortcut, and I put my Telltale Games account and password (only once, as it saves my credentials after the first launch). Then I select the first Episode and click **play**, and nothing happens!

Is there any solution for this?

---

I've already looked on the Internet, and found people reporting success after running the game as administrator. I don't want to run it as administrator (and it's more a workaround than a solution), and that's why I'm posting this question here, hoping to find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving yourself read/write/modify/delete permissions for the relevant Program Files directory that BTTF is installed in. This only opens up that single directory (rather than much more when you run as administrator).

Win7 is quite pedantic about applications without "elevated privileges" changing files in Program Files.

Comment: Okay, I've just tried this, and it doesn't seem to solve this issue. Not sure if I did something wrong (I guess not, Explorer says I have full permissions on all installed files), or if it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Denilson I'm not sure what the solution is then, other than running as administrator. I guess you could try installing the game somewhere other than Program Files and see if that works?